# how to create expandable list inside a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview, expandable

I have in a scrollview defined three main linear layout.

When on click on one of this layout I would like to expand a list with different options. How to do that?

I have something like this:

Currently I have:

Main.java:

```
linlayout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {..../ go to a new inntent}
 }
```

Main.xml:

```
Layout1
Layout2
Layout3
```

When clicking on Layout1 I would like to see:

```
Layout1
 Option1 
 Option2
 Option3
Layout2
Layout3
```

Can someone help me with the best solution to this? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this tutorial for your specification. Here is a link, [Click Here](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

Comment: I've posed a question regardin JSoup. Could you help? Thx